# Unity network spawn get delayed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I have implemented the network game like on the tutorial which the client will send the Cmd fire to server and then the server will spawn the bullet to all player.

Everything goes well when I played it on LAN (the ping is < 20ms). But when I try to run on internet side using the Match Maker, the ping is >80ms and the bullet get delayed on client.

The game is ship that able to shoot, so when the ship moving from left to right, then I shoot, the bullet got delayed. When i check on other games (non unity), it seems that the bullet is running locally. But it does not work on Unity, since the network object must be spawn on server. The delay shoot is only for my player. Is there any work around to fix the delay? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you can do is spawn the bullet locally for each client (Example: Enemy is shooting at Client, but Client is the one spawning Enemy's bullets, so that he can see them). So in theory you would just need the Enemy to tell the Client that he is about to shoot.

Comment: @Hristo : the delay only happen on my player. Not happen on anything else.

Comment: Then I think you should not make the bullets `network objects`.

Comment: what is the send rate?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the calculations of a hit client sided (So you calculate if you hit an enemy) and if you do hit the enemy you can send damage or a function/bool over the network.

That will greatly reduce trafic. And most likely solve your problem.

Take a look at this unity documentation for more info on how to sync lives.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/networking-player-health

Comment: But i need to have visual of the bullet on other client too